# temporarily block outgoing web traffic during work period

Tags: firewall, internet

I need for a given time period to put a speedbump against my tendency to be distracted by ad hoc web searches while working. I don't want to block LAN traffic because I keep a git server on one of my LAN hosts.

One implementation might be to install a firewall rule with an expiry time or time-to-live. I have UFW. There will be other solutions I'm sure.

Comment: Unclear on if your asking for a solution on your desktop or on a network firewall. Try closing firefox/chrome/chromium/opera/... on your desktop and you will no longer be distracted.

Comment: If a firewall fix then it will for a specified length or time block requests from my workstation to any location outside the LAN. I can easily open a browser instance on a whim, without premeditation, so I'm looking for a harder speedbump. Something that will require extra effort to disable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the proxy settings in Firefox. Here I assumed that your local network is `192.168.122.0/24`, but you have to adapt that to your own case.

[image: Firefox proxy settings]

Comment: That is a very cool idea, but I'm hoping for a solution with some expiry, and preferabley a one-click or command. I see there is a CLI for firefox and chrome that access proxy settings. Perhaps there is something there that could be scripted on a timer.

Comment: I understand, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to change that on the fly. Actually the best way might be to tick system proxy and change the proxy settings using gsettings as [there](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174486) using a cron or something.